# Invalid read of size 8 , at 0x400886: set_random_fill (app.c:60)

Tags: c

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

There is simple task, but I don't know how to write it correctly in C89.

`valgrind` says that there is an error at line 60

```
enter universe size:
22
==18369== Invalid read of size 8
==18369==    at 0x400886: set_random_fill (app.c:66)
==18369==    by 0x4007EE: main (app.c:42)
==18369==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

here is code (I use `clang`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
  int size;
  int *array;
} set ;

typedef struct {
  int size;
  set *array;
} set_collection;

void
set_allocate(set *allocatable_set, int numbers_amount);

void
set_random_fill(set *initializable_set);

void
set_print(set *printable_set);

int
main(void)
{
  int universe_size = 0;
  set *universe = NULL;

  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

  puts("enter universe size:");
  scanf("%d", &universe_size);

  set_allocate(universe, universe_size);
  set_random_fill(universe);
  set_print(universe);
  free(universe);

  return 0;
}

void
set_allocate(set *allocatable_set, int numbers_amount)
{
  allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));
  allocatable_set -> size = numbers_amount;
  allocatable_set -> array = calloc(
    (unsigned long) numbers_amount, sizeof(int)
  );
}

void
set_random_fill(set *initializable_set)
{
  int set_element_cursor = 0;
  int set_elements_amount = 0;
  int *set_elements_array = NULL;

  set_elements_array = initializable_set -> array;
  set_elements_amount = initializable_set -> size;

  while (set_element_cursor < set_elements_amount) {
    set_elements_array[set_element_cursor] = rand() % 100;
    ++set_element_cursor;
  }
}

void
set_print(set *printable_set)
{
  int set_size = 0;
  int set_element_cursor = 0;
  int *set_elements_array = NULL;

  set_size = printable_set -> size;
  set_elements_array = printable_set -> array;

  while (set_element_cursor < set_size) {
    printf("%d ", set_elements_array[set_element_cursor]);
    ++set_element_cursor;
  }
}
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: `set *universe = NULL;` --> `set *universe = malloc(sizeof(set));` instead of `allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));`. Also Need `free` for `int *array;`

Comment: According to "fail fast" strategy it's best to allocate in another function, isn't it?

Comment: You should do as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your allocate_Set function does not work as you think; passed pointer is passed by value an is local to the function. In other words the pointer passed and declared in main function is not modified by the function.

You have 2 options:

Return the allocated address back to main

```
set *set_allocate(int numbers_amount)
{
    set *allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));
    if (allocatable_set != NULL)
    {
        allocatable_set->size = numbers_amount;
        allocatable_set->array = calloc((unsigned long) numbers_amount, sizeof(int));
        if (allocatable_set->array == NULL)
        {
            free(allocatable_set);
            allocatable_set = NULL;
        }
    }

    return allocatable_set;
}
```

and call it from main as

```
set *universe = set_allocate(universe_size);
```

---

using a double pointer

```
void set_allocate(set **allocatable_set, int numbers_amount)
{
    *allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));
    if (*allocatable_set != NULL)
    {
        *allocatable_set->size = numbers_amount;
        *allocatable_set->array = calloc((unsigned long) numbers_amount, sizeof(int));
        if (*allocatable_set->array == NULL)
        {
            free(allocatable_set);
            *allocatable_set = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it from main

```
set_allocate(&universe, universe_size);
```

Comment: Thanks! But, if in automatic variable has been created, what value it had? Why it's not the same memory address?

Comment: @LexUshakov Passing a pointer to a function make you able, in function, to dereference a memory: in other words we can say you are passing by value the address pointed by the pointer. But the pointer itself, inside the function, is only a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

C is pass-by-*value*.  This code does not change the value of the `set *` pointer passed in:

```
void
set_allocate(set *allocatable_set, int numbers_amount)
{
  allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));
  allocatable_set -> size = numbers_amount;
  allocatable_set -> array = calloc(
    (unsigned long) numbers_amount, sizeof(int)
  );
}
```

Given

```
  set *universe = NULL;

  ...

  set_allocate(universe, universe_size);
  set_random_fill(universe);
```

`universe` is still `NULL` for the call to `set_random_fill`.

Something like this works:

```
set *
set_allocate( int numbers_amount)
{
  set *allocatable_set = malloc(sizeof(set));
  if ( allocatable_set == NULL )
  {
      return( NULL );
  }
  allocatable_set -> size = numbers_amount;
  allocatable_set -> array = calloc(
    (unsigned long) numbers_amount, sizeof(int)
  );

  return( allocatable_set );
}
```

then call it:

```
 set *universe = set_allocate( universe_size );
```

Comment: But, if in automatic variable has been created, what value it had? Why it's not the same memory address? It's copy the struct referred to function via pointer?